# How can I transform a series of lists of dictionaries into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, transform

I have the following dataframe. Genres column is a list of multiple dictionaries.

```
index. title    genres
0      Avatar                                       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
1      Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End     [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}]
2      Spectre                                      [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]
3      The Dark Knight Rises                        [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}, {"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 53, "name": "Thriller"}]
4      John Carter                                  [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
```

I would like to have a dataframe as follows:

```
     Title   Name
     Avatar  Action
     Avatar  Adventure
     Avatar  Fantasy
     Avatar  Science Fiction
     Pirates.. Adventure
     Pirates.. Fantasy
     ...
```

I hope the questions is clear. It is my first time posting a question.
Thanks,

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. This way folks can help you with the problem efficiently.

Comment: After thinking and googling for 2 hours, I unfortunately still had no idea how to approach this. How can I clarify more what I need?

Comment: Where does that data come from, why is it in the DataFrame like that?

Comment: I downloaded a CSV file from kaggle.com. The format is apparently in that shape already in the CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a df:

```
df
    title   genres
0   Avatar  [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
1   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End    [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}]
2   Spectre [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]
3   The Dark Knight Rises   [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}, {"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 53, "name": "Thriller"}]
4   John Carter [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
```

Then we can do:

```
df["genres"] = df["genres"].apply(lambda row: [genre["name"] for genre in row])
df.explode("genres")
    title   genres
0   Avatar  Action
0   Avatar  Adventure
0   Avatar  Fantasy
0   Avatar  Science Fiction
1   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End    Adventure
1   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End    Fantasy
1   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End    Action
2   Spectre Action
2   Spectre Adventure
2   Spectre Crime
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Action
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Crime
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Drama
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Thriller
4   John Carter Action
4   John Carter Adventure
4   John Carter Science Fiction
```

Comment: Oh, `df.explode` instead of exploding a series! +1

Comment: Sorry, when I use atkilat90's dataframe, your cord works perfectly fine. But when I create my dataframe from my original dataframe with 'df = imdb[['title','genres']]' then I get the 'string indices must be integers' error from your code. Can you think of a reason? Thank you!

Comment: How do you create your imdb dataframe? If you read your data from disk you have to use `import ast; imdb = pd.read_csv(filepath, convertes={"genres":ast.literal_eval});`. Otherwise you'll get list of dictionaries as a string. Hence your error.

Comment: Woww. Thanks a lot. I get that. I could see the difference know when check the type of a row of genres series. With your method, I get a list, otherwise just a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
title = ["Avatar", "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End", "Spectre", "The Dark Knight Rises", "John Carter" ]
genres = [[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}],
          [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}],
          [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}],
          [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}, {"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 53, "name": "Thriller"}],
          [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]]
df = pd.DataFrame({"title": title,
                   "genres": genres})
```

Exploding the dictionary series :

```
genres_list = df["genres"].apply(lambda x: [y["name"] for y in x ]).explode()
genres_list

0             Action
0          Adventure
0            Fantasy
0    Science Fiction
1          Adventure
1            Fantasy
1             Action
2             Action
2          Adventure
2              Crime
3             Action
3              Crime
3              Drama
3           Thriller
4             Action
4          Adventure
4    Science Fiction
Name: genres, dtype: object
```

Expanding the titles:

Each element in `df["title"]`, is repeated by `n_i` times, where `n_i` is the length of the respective dictionary. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html).

```
title_rep = df["title"].repeat(df["genres"].apply(lambda x: len(x)))
title_rep

0                                      Avatar
0                                      Avatar
0                                      Avatar
0                                      Avatar
1    Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End
1    Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End
1    Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End
2                                     Spectre
2                                     Spectre
2                                     Spectre
3                       The Dark Knight Rises
3                       The Dark Knight Rises
3                       The Dark Knight Rises
3                       The Dark Knight Rises
4                                 John Carter
4                                 John Carter
4                                 John Carter
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Combining:

```
pd.DataFrame({"title": title_rep,
              "genres": genres_list})
```

Returns:

```
            title   genres
0   Avatar  Action
0   Avatar  Adventure
0   Avatar  Fantasy
0   Avatar  Science Fiction
1   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End    Adventure
1   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End    Fantasy
1   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End    Action
2   Spectre Action
2   Spectre Adventure
2   Spectre Crime
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Action
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Crime
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Drama
3   The Dark Knight Rises   Thriller
4   John Carter Action
4   John Carter Adventure
4   John Carter Science Fiction
```

Comment: I'm wondering how did you get those `title` and `genres` to start with? By hand? Editing the OP?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov yes, I had to. It would've been easier if I could use `pd.read_clipboard` or `StringIO`

Comment: Thank you very much. That works, now I am trying to understand how that expanding works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"title":["Avatar","Spectre"],"genres":[
                    [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}],
                    [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]
                    ]})

print(df)

     title                                             genres
0   Avatar  [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 12, 'nam...
1  Spectre  [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 12, 'nam...
```

Get only names from the "genres" column

```
df["genres"] = df["genres"].apply(lambda x:[y.get("name") for y in x])
```

Create a new dataframe with only names:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df["genres"].values.tolist())
df1.columns = ["name_{}".format(x) for x in range(len(df1.columns))]
```

Combine both:

```
df = pd.concat([df[["title"]],df1],axis=1)
```

Melt:

```
df.melt(id_vars="title",value_vars=df.columns[1:],value_name="name")[["title","name"]].dropna().set_index("title").sort_index()



                 name
title
Avatar            Action
Avatar         Adventure
Avatar           Fantasy
Avatar   Science Fiction
Spectre           Action
Spectre        Adventure
Spectre            Crime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = "dataframe"
df_list = []
```

> Iterate through each row and gets values of Title and genres columns

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    title = row['title']
    gn = row['genres']
    genres = ast.literal_eval(gn)

    for i in range(0, len(genres)):
        r_list = []
        r_list.append(title)
        r_list.append(genres[i]['name'])
        df_list.append(r_list)

out_df = pd.DataFrame(df_list,columns=['Title','Name'])
print(out_df.head)
```

> if values of column genres are of type string, then we need to convert it in to list, for that we use "ast.literal_eval()"